# Cant deploy to app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

When I was trying to deploy a project to APP engine for the second time in the same version, it said:

```
Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=adaptivecourse&version=122&
409 Conflict
Another transaction by user jyothirmayi.prasad is already in progress for app: s~adaptivecourse, version: 122. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".
```

I couldn't understand the reason behind it.
So, all i could do is to deploy the project to another version.
What actually happened?

Comment: Are you the only user with update privileges? If you aborted the first installation (e.g. with `CTRL-C` in the command line) then the update will be locked in the previous transaction. As the error text suggests, you can run the command `appcfg rollback` to fix the error.

Comment: I was not only the one with privileges. And Can you tell me how to run that appcfg rollback command

Comment: `appcfg rollback <dir>` according to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Command_Line_Arguments